# Pragmatically bouncing ball animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I tried to implement my ball animation as shown in the given image and code, but I am not able to get result as per the requirement.

Can anyone help me out how to solve this issue?

I also have to control the bouncing part because actually I want to integrate this part in my app so that when data is loaded from the server the ball has to stop bouncing in the middle and follow the path as shown.

**Code:**

```
package tedd.example.com.aprilbouncing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new BallBounce(this));
    }
}


class BallBounce extends View {
    int screenW;
    int screenH;
    float X;
    int Y;
    int initialY;
    int initialX;
    int ballW;
    int ballH;
    int angle;
    float dY;
    float acc;
    Bitmap ball, bgr;
    int count;

    public BallBounce(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball); //load a ball image
        //bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sky_bgr); //load a background
        ballW = ball.getWidth();
        ballH = ball.getHeight();
        acc = 0.2f; //acceleration
        dY = 0; //vertical speed
        initialY = 400; //Initial vertical position.
        initialX = 0;
        angle = 0; //Start value for rotation angle.
        count=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;
       // bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w, h, true); //Resize background to fit the screen.
        //X = (int) (screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ; //Centre ball into the centre of the screen.
        X = initialX;
        Y = initialY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Draw background.
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        //Compute roughly ball speed and location.
        X =(screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ;

        if(count==1){
        X =(screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ;
        }

        if(count>4){

        }
        if(count>=4){
            X+=1;
        }
        Y+= (int) dY; //Increase or decrease vertical position.
        if (Y > (screenH - ballH)) {
            dY=(-1)*dY; //Reverse speed when bottom hit.
            count++;
        }
        dY+= acc; //Increase or decrease speed.

        //Increase rotating angle.
        if (angle++ >360)
            angle =0;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(angle*8, X + (ballW / 2), Y + (ballH / 2));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, X, Y, null);
        canvas.restore();

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**Image:**

[image: Ball's path image]

or 
[image: as shown here]

Comment: "i am not able to get result as per the requirement" - that's highly unspecific.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? What have you got working at the moment? What do you want it to do? What is the problem you're having getting from what you have to what you want?

Comment: from my code as mentioned above ,my ball is bouncing at center only,but i want my ball has to start from the left side of screen ,has to hit the middle bottom of the screen just before going have the first bounce ,and the number of bounce in that position(center) as to be controlled which means  i can control the number of bounces and after that my ball has bounce as well as at the same time it has cross from left side of the screen

Comment: Good idea asking for a pragmatic solution, too often you get over-complicated solutions, and that's just not good.   ;)

Comment: @ Daniel Nugent No problem ,whatever the solution i want result android animation as shown :)If you have kindly provide me even if you have any other way of programming/solution  is also fine but has to implement that in android :)

Comment: anyone got the solution for this? :)